# How to find in which folder/app group is an app icon?

Tags: search, home-screen-folders

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S6 on Android 7.0. I cannot find a way to locate in which folder/app_group I misplaced an app icon.

On iOS, you can achieve this very easily:
If you searched for an app, you will see an app icon—which you can tap to launch the program—as well as a **header that tells you in which folder the app is stored**.

If I use the search in the app drawer (GO Launcher Z or the default TouchWiz home screen app), I can easily find the app icon, but it will not let me know in which folder/app_group the icon is.

**This is a search example (for the Netflix icon/app):**

[image]

You can see that the icon is located in the media folder. In this case, it is easy to find, but when a folder holds more than 4 icons locating an icon is tedious.

[image]

How to find in which folder/app group is an app icon?

Comment: This may work- Install [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) .  Under *Backup and Import settings* you have an option of importing current desktop layout and hopefully you should get the folders. Next, tap on the 3 for at bottom of folder boundary , where it gives you an option of adding more apps in a list. That list has existing apps checked - that's what you want

Comment: I meant 3 button menu at the bottom corner of the folder

Comment: @beeshyams: only the paid version of Nova Launcher enables  the use of the  drawer groups.  If I do not get other suggestions, I will buy and ask for a refund as a "proof of concept"

Answer (score 0):

If you search in apps, locate the icon in the results and then press and hold on that button you will get a short pop-up menu which includes "Locate" that does the job nicely, *(not sure which version introduced this feature).*